# Make IE7 compatible using CSS conditional comment

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, x-ua-compatible

I've been struggling to make my website IE7 Compatible. I'm using this code is my `head` tag to ensure that if the website is running on IE7 it should use jquery 1.7 instead of jquery 2.1.

```
 <!--[if IE 7]>
  <script src="../../common/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="../../common/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

But I'm still getting error like this : 
[image]

Which means that the website is still using Jquery-2.1.1, but I'm testing it on IE7.

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second one does it! So load it first!

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="../../common/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
  <script src="../../common/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Or make the `2.1.1`, greater than IE 7!

```
<!--[if gt IE 7]>
  <script src="../../common/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I don't understand. So my condition is invalid?

Comment: What's `lt IE 9`? Less than IE 9. IE 7 **is** less than IE 9!